# Perl script dying

Tags: perl, nlp

I have never ever written Perl and I'm trying to run the perl script in http://www.statmt.org/europarl/

which should align sentences between two corpora.

However, when I do

```
perl sentence-align-corpus.perl
```

I get this-

```
  Use of uninitialized value $l1 in concatenation (.) or string at sentence-align-corpus.perl line 17.
Died at sentence-align-corpus.perl line 17.
```

When I do

```
 perl sentence-align-corpus.perl europarlEnglishCorpus.txt europarlSpanishCorpus.txt
```

I get this

```
Died at sentence-align-corpus.perl line 17.
```

Why?

code(sorry I didn't know I could open the perl file in my txt editor- it looked like an executable)

```
   #!/usr/bin/perl -w

use FindBin qw($Bin);
use strict;
use Encode;

binmode(STDIN, ":utf8");
binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");
binmode(STDERR, ":utf8");

chdir($Bin);
my $dir = "txt";
my $outdir = "aligned";
my $preprocessor = "$Bin/tools/split-sentences.perl -q";

my ($l1,$l2) = @ARGV;
die unless -e "$dir/$l1";
die unless -e "$dir/$l2";

`mkdir -p $outdir/$l1-$l2/$l1`;
`mkdir -p $outdir/$l1-$l2/$l2`;

my ($dayfile,$s1); # globals for reporting reasons
open(LS,"ls $dir/$l1|");
while($dayfile = <LS>) {
  chop($dayfile);
  if (! -e "$dir/$l2/$dayfile") {
    print "$dayfile only for $l1, not $l2, skipping\n";
    next;
  }
  &align();
}

sub align {
  my @TXT1native= `$preprocessor -l $l1 < $dir/$l1/$dayfile`;
  my @TXT2native = `$preprocessor -l $l2 < $dir/$l2/$dayfile`;
  my @TXT1;
  my @TXT2;


  #change perl encoding
  foreach my $line (@TXT1native) {
    push(@TXT1,decode_utf8($line));
  }
foreach my $line (@TXT2native) {
    push(@TXT2,decode_utf8($line));
  }  

  open(OUT1, ">$outdir/$l1-$l2/$l1/$dayfile");
  open(OUT2, ">$outdir/$l1-$l2/$l2/$dayfile");

    binmode(OUT1, ":utf8");
    binmode(OUT2, ":utf8");


  for(my $i2=0,my $i1=0; $i1<scalar(@TXT1) && $i2<scalar(@TXT2);) {

    # match chapter start
    if ($TXT1[$i1] =~ /^<CHAPTER ID=\"?(\d+)\"?/) {
      my $c1 = $1;
      #print "CHAPTER $1\n";
      if ($TXT2[$i2] =~ /^<CHAPTER ID=\"?(\d+)\"?/) {
    my $c2 = $1;
    if ($c1 == $c2) {
      print OUT1 $TXT1[$i1++];
      print OUT2 $TXT2[$i2++];
    }
    elsif ($c1 < $c2) {
      $i1 = &skip(\@TXT1,$i1+1,'^<CHAPTER ID=\"?\d+\"?');
    }
    else {
      $i2 = &skip(\@TXT2,$i2+1,'^<CHAPTER ID=\"?\d+\"?');
    }
      }
      else {
    $i2 = &skip(\@TXT2,$i2,'^<CHAPTER ID=\"?\d+\"?');
      }
    }

    # match speaker start
    elsif ($TXT1[$i1] =~ /^<SPEAKER ID=\"?(\d+)\"?/) {
      $s1 = $1;
      #print "SPEAKER $1\n";
      if ($TXT2[$i2] =~ /^<SPEAKER ID=\"?(\d+)\"?/) {
    my $s2 = $1;
    if ($s1 == $s2) {
      print OUT1 $TXT1[$i1++];
      print OUT2 $TXT2[$i2++];
    }
    elsif ($s1 < $s2) {
      $i1 = &skip(\@TXT1,$i1+1,'^<SPEAKER ID=\"?\d+\"?');
    }
    else {
      $i2 = &skip(\@TXT2,$i2+1,'^<SPEAKER ID=\"?\d+\"?');
    }
      }
      else {
    $i2 = &skip(\@TXT2,$i2,'^<SPEAKER ID=\"?\d+\"?');
      }
    }  
    else {
      #print "processing... $i1,$i2\n";
      my @P1 = &extract_paragraph(\@TXT1,\$i1);
      my @P2 = &extract_paragraph(\@TXT2,\$i2);
      if (scalar(@P1) != scalar(@P2)) {
    print "$dayfile (speaker $s1) different number of paragraphs ".scalar(@P1)." != ".scalar(@P2)."\n";
      }
      else {
      for(my $p=0;$p<scalar(@P1);$p++) {
          &sentence_align(\@{$P1[$p]},\@{$P2[$p]});
      }
      }
    }
  }
}
close(LS);

sub skip {
  my ($TXT,$i,$pattern) = @_;
  my $i_old = $i;
  while($i < scalar(@{$TXT})
    && $$TXT[$i] !~ /$pattern/) { 
    $i++; 
  }
  print "$dayfile skipped lines $i_old-$i to reach '$pattern'\n";
  return $i;
}

sub extract_paragraph {
  my ($TXT,$i) = @_;
  my @P = ();
  my $p=0;
  for(;$$i<scalar(@{$TXT}) 
      && ${$TXT}[$$i] !~ /^<SPEAKER ID=\"?\d+\"?/
      && ${$TXT}[$$i] !~ /^<CHAPTER ID=\"?\d+\"?/;$$i++) {
    if (${$TXT}[$$i] =~ /^<P>/) {
    $p++ if $P[$p];
    # each XML tag has its own paragraph
    push @{$P[$p]}, ${$TXT}[$$i];
    $p++;
    }
    else {
      push @{$P[$p]}, ${$TXT}[$$i];
    }
  }
  return @P;
}

# this is a vanilla implementation of church and gale
sub sentence_align {
  my ($P1,$P2) = @_;
  chop(@{$P1});
  chop(@{$P2});

  # parameters
  my %PRIOR;
  $PRIOR{1}{1} = 0.89;
  $PRIOR{1}{0} = 0.01/2;
  $PRIOR{0}{1} = 0.01/2;
  $PRIOR{2}{1} = 0.089/2;
  $PRIOR{1}{2} = 0.089/2;
#  $PRIOR{2}{2} = 0.011;

  # compute length (in characters)
  my (@LEN1,@LEN2);
  $LEN1[0] = 0;
  for(my $i=0;$i<scalar(@{$P1});$i++) {
    my $line = $$P1[$i];
    $line =~ s/[\s\r\n]+//g;
#    print "1: $line\n";
    $LEN1[$i+1] = $LEN1[$i] + length($line);
  }
  $LEN2[0] = 0;
  for(my $i=0;$i<scalar(@{$P2});$i++) {
    my $line = $$P2[$i];
    $line =~ s/[\s\r\n]+//g;
#    print "2: $line\n";
    $LEN2[$i+1] = $LEN2[$i] + length($line);
  }

  # dynamic programming
  my (@COST,@BACK);
  $COST[0][0] = 0;
  for(my $i1=0;$i1<=scalar(@{$P1});$i1++) {
    for(my $i2=0;$i2<=scalar(@{$P2});$i2++) {
      next if $i1 + $i2 == 0;
      $COST[$i1][$i2] = 1e10;
      foreach my $d1 (keys %PRIOR) {
    next if $d1>$i1;
    foreach my $d2 (keys %{$PRIOR{$d1}}) {
      next if $d2>$i2;
      my $cost = $COST[$i1-$d1][$i2-$d2] - log($PRIOR{$d1}{$d2}) +  
        &match($LEN1[$i1]-$LEN1[$i1-$d1], $LEN2[$i2]-$LEN2[$i2-$d2]);
#     print "($i1->".($i1-$d1).",$i2->".($i2-$d2).") [".($LEN1[$i1]-$LEN1[$i1-$d1]).",".($LEN2[$i2]-$LEN2[$i2-$d2])."] = $COST[$i1-$d1][$i2-$d2] - ".log($PRIOR{$d1}{$d2})." + ".&match($LEN1[$i1]-$LEN1[$i1-$d1], $LEN2[$i2]-$LEN2[$i2-$d2])." = $cost\n";
      if ($cost < $COST[$i1][$i2]) {
        $COST[$i1][$i2] = $cost;
        @{$BACK[$i1][$i2]} = ($i1-$d1,$i2-$d2);
      }
    }
      }
#      print $COST[$i1][$i2]."($i1-$BACK[$i1][$i2][0],$i2-$BACK[$i1][$i2][1]) ";
    }
#    print "\n";
  }

  # back tracking
  my (%NEXT);
  my $i1 = scalar(@{$P1});
  my $i2 = scalar(@{$P2});
  while($i1>0 || $i2>0) {
#    print "back $i1 $i2\n";
    @{$NEXT{$BACK[$i1][$i2][0]}{$BACK[$i1][$i2][1]}} = ($i1,$i2);
    ($i1,$i2) = ($BACK[$i1][$i2][0],$BACK[$i1][$i2][1]);
  }
  while($i1<scalar(@{$P1}) || $i2<scalar(@{$P2})) {
#    print "fwd $i1 $i2\n";
    for(my $i=$i1;$i<$NEXT{$i1}{$i2}[0];$i++) {
      print OUT1 " " unless $i == $i1;
      print OUT1 $$P1[$i];
    }
    print OUT1 "\n";
    for(my $i=$i2;$i<$NEXT{$i1}{$i2}[1];$i++) {
      print OUT2 " " unless $i == $i2;
      print OUT2 $$P2[$i];
    }
    print OUT2 "\n";
    ($i1,$i2) = @{$NEXT{$i1}{$i2}};
  }  
}

sub match {
  my ($len1,$len2) = @_;
  my $c = 1;
  my $s2 = 6.8;

  if ($len1==0 && $len2==0) { return 0; }
  my $mean = ($len1 + $len2/$c) / 2;
  my $z = ($c * $len1 - $len2)/sqrt($s2 * $mean);
  if ($z < 0) { $z = -$z; }
  my $pd = 2 * (1 - &pnorm($z));
  if ($pd>0) { return -log($pd); }
  return 25;
}

sub pnorm {
  my ($z) = @_;
  my $t = 1/(1 + 0.2316419 * $z);
  return 1 - 0.3989423 * exp(-$z * $z / 2) *
    ((((1.330274429 * $t 
    - 1.821255978) * $t 
       + 1.781477937) * $t 
      - 0.356563782) * $t
     + 0.319381530) * $t;
}
```

Comment: Humor us and show us line 17. Maybe lines 16 and 15, too.

Comment: sorry- didn't know I could open the perl file in a txt file.

Comment: `$l1` and `$l2` are never declared nor defined.  But that should be a strictures error (compiletime). Can you paste the part of the script where those two variables get assigned values?

Comment: I'll just post the entire script - it is freely available

Comment: It is assuming that that the corpus files are in a directory called text.

Comment: what should the location of the directory be?

Comment: so I added the corpora into a directory called text, same error though

Comment: Well, my guess is that there's no directory named `$Bin/txt`, for whatever your value of $Bin happens to be, or possibly that in `$Bin/txt/` there is no `europarlEnglishCorpus.txt` and `europarlSpanishCorpus.txt` file.  Are you sure you put them in the right place before invoking the script?

Answer (score 2):

Your script expects two filenames to be present on the command line and expects that a directory called "txt" exists in which those files are found. It sets $l1 and $l2 using those arguments. Your terminal command should be
perl sentence-align-corpus.perl **file1 file2**

Both file1 and file2 must exist in a directory called "txt."

Answer (score 1):

This could be helpful to find out why command line arguments are failing,

```
die "No $dir/$l1, I must die" unless -e "$dir/$l1";
die "No $dir/$l2, I'll die now" unless -e "$dir/$l2";
```